# DTFT (Discrete Time Fourier Transform) duality property applied to cos / sin

Tags: fourier-transform, z-transform

Normal DTFT table contains:

$$
\cos(\omega_0 n)  \xrightarrow{DTFT\ 2\pi} \pi \delta[\omega - \omega_0] + \pi \delta[\omega + \omega_0]
$$

$$
\sin(\omega_0 n)  \xrightarrow{DTFT\ 2\pi} i\ \pi\ \delta[\omega - \omega_0] - i\ \pi \ \delta[\omega + \omega_0]
$$

How would I apply "duality property" to obtain DTFT transform for:

$$
???   \xrightarrow{DTFT\ 2\pi} \cos(\omega_0\ \omega)
$$

$$
???   \xrightarrow{DTFT\ 2\pi} \sin(\omega_0\ \omega)
$$

??? = fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you don't need to use duality to derive DTFT of sin and cos in reverse.  You just need to use these identities:

$$
cos(\omega) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{i\ \omega}+e^{-i\ \omega})
$$

$$
sin(\omega) = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{i\ \omega}-e^{-i\ \omega})
$$

Then the following DTFT Transforms:

$$
\delta[n-d] \xrightarrow{DTFT} e^{-i\ \omega\ d}
$$